# Blurhash octoimage bug

Tags: flutter, dart

## Mentioned the error and the code snippet kindly check into this and help me solve it!

**ERROR**
The method 'blurHash' isn't defined for the type 'OctoImage'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'blurHash'.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
 Widget buildOcto(height) {
    int cachingHeight = widget.cachingHeight;
    int cachingWidth = widget.cachingWidth;
    if (widget.aspectRatio != 1 && cachingHeight == 720) cachingHeight = 960;
    return OctoImage(
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.url,
          maxWidth: cachingWidth, maxHeight: cachingHeight),
      errorBuilder: (context, url, error) => buildError(),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: widget.width ?? double.infinity,
      height: widget.height ?? height,
      placeholderBuilder: widget.blurHash.isNotEmpty
          ? OctoImage.**blurHash**(widget.blurHash, fit: BoxFit.cover)
          : (context) => Center(child: loadingWidget()),
    );
  }
```

**Attaching screenshot**
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1OcJ.png)

Comment: you can try this package [hash_cached_image](https://pub.dev/packages/hash_cached_image) in this package you can use `hashimage` and `cachenetworkimage` both at a same time.

Comment: Any idea why the above error occurred?

Comment: Did you get the code for `OctoImage.blurHash` from ChatGPT (or other LLM)?

Comment: Took some help from github!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/octo_image/changelog#200---2023-09-25), the blurhash feature has been removed from the package in the version 2.0.0. To keep using blurhash with octo_image, you can follow [this guide](https://pub.dev/packages/octo_image#blurhash) from the readme to create your own OctoSet` with blurhash as the placeholder:

```dart
/// Simple set to show [OctoPlaceholder.circularProgressIndicator] as
/// placeholder and [OctoError.icon] as error.
OctoSet blurHash(
  String hash, {
  BoxFit? fit,
  Text? errorMessage,
}) {
  return OctoSet(
    placeholderBuilder: blurHashPlaceholderBuilder(hash, fit: fit),
    errorBuilder: blurHashErrorBuilder(hash, fit: fit),
  );
}

OctoPlaceholderBuilder blurHashPlaceholderBuilder(String hash, {BoxFit? fit}) {
  return (context) => SizedBox.expand(
    child: Image(
      image: BlurHashImage(hash),
      fit: fit ?? BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  );
}


OctoErrorBuilder blurHashErrorBuilder(
  String hash, {
  BoxFit? fit,
  Text? message,
  IconData? icon,
  Color? iconColor,
  double? iconSize,
}) {
  return OctoError.placeholderWithErrorIcon(
    blurHashPlaceholderBuilder(hash, fit: fit),
    message: message,
    icon: icon,
    iconColor: iconColor,
    iconSize: iconSize,
  );
}
```

Now you can use the `blurHash` function to create your `OctoSet`:

```dart
blurHash(widget.blurHash, fit: BoxFit.cover)
```

Comment: I tried to resolve it as per you mentioned but still the problem persist!

Comment: You use it by calling the function directly: `blurHash(widget.blurHash, fit: BoxFit.cover)`, so just `blurHash` not `OctoImage.blurHash`